# Multiple constructors of length 2. Unable to disambiguate with Unity

Tags: c#, mongodb, dependency-injection, unity-container

I want to use DI with a Repository Class and Interface for MongoDB, but it's not working. I have this error:

> The type MongoRepository`1 has multiple constructors of length 2. Unable to disambiguate.

Class Constructors:

```
    public MongoRepository(string connectionString, string collectionName)
    {
        this.collection = Util<TKey>.GetCollectionFromConnectionString<T>(connectionString, collectionName);
    }


    public MongoRepository(MongoUrl url, string collectionName)
    {
        this.collection = Util<TKey>.GetCollectionFromUrl<T>(url, collectionName);
    }
```

Unity Config:

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(MongoRepository.IRepository<>), typeof(MongoRepository.MongoRepository<>));
```

How can I configure the DI in Unity? Thanks!!

Comment: Honestly, and people will flame me for this, the real solution is to stop using Unity and use a decent IoC container like Autofac that handles about anything you want to throw at it. Unity falls over at practically every hurdle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is simple: don't use auto-wiring when dealing with framework types, as explained in [this article](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97).

Instead register a factory delegate for framework types. This however won't work in your case since you're dealing with a generic type, but the work around again is simple: create a derived type and register that:

```
public class MyMongoRepository<T> : MongoRepository<T>
{
    // of course you should fill in the real connection string here.
    public MyMongoRepository() : base("connectionString", "name") { }
}

container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(MyMongoRepository<>));
```

Comment: Why it solves my problem? container.RegisterType<MongoRepository.IRepository<Genially>, MongoRepository.MongoRepository<Genially>>
               (new InjectionConstructor());

Comment: @chemitaxis: It solves your problem because now you have a generic type with a constructor that Unity knows how to call. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 8):

Note that you can also tell Unity which constructor it should use:

```
//Use the MongoRepository(string, string) constructor:
container.RegisterType(
    typeof(IRepository<>), 
    typeof(MyMongoRepository<>),
    new InjectionConstructor(typeof(string), typeof(string)));
```

Comment: This solution worked for me and is simpler than the accepted answer